# How do I transpose columns into rows using tree in SQL? Is there any tree in sql command to transpose?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions, unpivot

**We are trying to output for each customer column should have 12 budgeted row entries for every month.**
 **Scenario 1:**

```
    ie. Turn table data  :
        Name    BudMnt1|BudMnt2|BudMnt3
        cust1   0           0   0
        cust2   0           0   0
        cust3   2418        0   0   
        cust4   0         416   198




into this :
        Name    cust1|  cust2|  cust3|  cust4
        BudMnt1 0          0    24180   0
        BudMnt2 0          0    0       416
        BudMnt3 0          0    0       198
```

**Scenario 2:
Includes Scenario 1 column as Budget+ additional column is sales solumn here 
so, it becomes two column budget ,sales which needs to unpivot on single query structure.**

```
ie. Turn table data  :
Name    JanSales|FebSales|MarSales
cust1        0          0    0
cust2        0          0    0
cust3        0          0    3
cust4        2          0    0

into this :
Name    cust1|cust2|cust3|cust4
JanSales    0   0   0   2
Feb Sales   0   0   0   0
Mar Sales   0   0   3   0
```

**Any HELP would be much appreciated !**

Comment: Since I can't see tags I cannot know what type of SQL syntax you are talking about. But in Oracle this would be the PIVOT syntax (I think)

Comment: and you have a fixed set of customers?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. We are looking for microsoft sql server 2012 syntax. yes,we do have fixed set of customers

Comment: Want to introduce one more scenario. when customer  is not fixed is also our concern while creating report dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

This link may help you as a reference to your question:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/04346f7c-0923-432d-83c3-22bf759dea22/transpose-data-from-columns-into-rows-using-sql

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine. Tasted it on sql server 2012.

```
SELECT  NAME ,
        budmtn ,
        cust
INTO    #temptable
FROM    ( SELECT    *
          FROM      tbl1
        ) AS result UNPIVOT ( cust FOR budmtn IN ( budmtn1, budmtn2, budmtn3 ) ) AS unpivotedtable 

SELECT  budmtn ,
        cust1 ,
        cust2 ,
        cust3 ,
        cust4
FROM    #temptable PIVOT( SUM(cust) FOR NAME IN ( cust1, cust2, cust3, cust4 ) ) AS result
```

Comment: Thanks a ton , it is  working  nice. i do have scenario in which  need to  do multiple column unpivot  can you  please  help me  as i have to unpivot budget , sales column together. Any help on it  would be much appreciated .

Comment: Can you post a sample so that I can figure out the problem?

Comment: We have updated the sample problem scenario.please let me know if you have any question on it.

Comment: I don't know what you wanted to ask, sorry. The second scenario you posted is similar to the first one and you can use  the answer I provided. All you have to do it unpivot it to three column intermediate  result on which you can do the pivot operation to arrive at the structure you wanted.